# How to share 4 counter variables between various threads in the same thread group in jmeter.Where to keep the initial values?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

> /*  Hello
>
> I need to generate 1 million json requests for load testing in >jmeter.Each thread will run each request. I have created a thread 
>   group.Each json request should look something like this:*/

```
      {
                "transaction_id": "TestTransactionId_1522743726505_0",
                "document_id": "TestDocumentId_1522743726505_200",
                "sender_id": "TestSenderId_1522743726505",
                "receiver_id": "TestReceiverId_1522743726505",
                "process_name": "TRANSACTION_TRACKING_PURCHASEORDER",
                "changed_by": "TestChangedBy_1522743726505",
                "system_id": "TestSystemId_1522743726505",
                "correlation_id": "TestDocumentId_1522743726505_200",
                "order_date": "1522743726505",
                "document_date": "1522743726505",
                "alert_type": "SUCCESS",
                "event_name": "TestEvent_1522743726505_200_0_0",
                "event_timestamp": "1522743726505",
                "event_id": "a907c672-a6bb-4295-a886-22fd1ba0b5f0",
                "host": "TestHost",
                "date_happened": "1522743726505",
                "reference_payload_id": "TestDocumentId_1522743726505_200",
                "error_message": "TestError_1522743726505",
                "source": "CIG",
                "attachment_document_type": "TRANSACTION_TRACKING_PURCHASEORDER"
            }


  /*  I need to generate this using 4 counter variables which are dependent upon each other. Following is the code for the same:
Can someone help me how to achieve this. My problem is that the threads are getting initialized everytime and its not picking the updated value. I am using jmeter groovy.*/

if (currentEventInDoc == 0) {
               currentDoc = (currentDoc+1)%numberOfDocPerOrder;
           }

           if (currentEventInDoc == 0 && currentDoc == 0) {
               currentOrder++;
           }      

        I
```

Comment: Just a reminder, If you need 1 million threads to generate 1 million requests then I bet you also need thousands of machines in the distributed architecture to replicate your scenario!!!

Comment: True. I have a distributed architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good use case for [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) as this is the only way to share values across multiple JMeter Engines.

You can add new entries or read existing ones using normal [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if you need to increment a counter value you can go for [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)